# Bar chart not displaying axes and legend values correctly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on a page that uses datatables to retrieve highcharts. Charts for Buttons one and three are fine. The problem I am facing is with Button two - Bar chart. For the chart, I am trying to display the values from column 2022 as Y axis and Percent column as X axis. The legend should also display Y axis columns. What am I missing? Here is my code.

```js
// Function to initialize Highcharts charts
function initializeChart(chartId, chartTitle, chartData, chartType) {
    Highcharts.chart(chartId, {
        chart: {
            type: chartType,
            styledMode: false
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
        colors: ['#1a4480', '#e52207', '#e66f0e', '#ffbe2e', '#fee685', '#538200', '#04c585', '#97d4ea', '#009ec1', '#0076d6', '#adadad', '#8168b3', '#d72d79', '#f2938c'],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '</b> {point.y:.1f}%'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "12px"
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: true
            },
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: "12px"
                    }
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            symbolRadius: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: chartData
        }]
    });
}

// Function to retrieve chart data from DataTable
function getChartData(table) {
    const data = [];
    table.rows().every(function () {
        const row = this.data();
        data.push({
            name: row[0],
            y: parseFloat(row[1])
        });
    });
    return data;
}

// Check if DataTable and Highcharts are defined before calling the function
if (typeof DataTable !== 'undefined' && typeof Highcharts !== 'undefined') {
    initializeCharts();
}

function initializeCharts() {
    const table1 = new DataTable('#example1', {
        searching: false,
        info: true,
        paging: false,
        sort: false
    });
    const table2 = new DataTable('#example', {
        searching: false,
        info: true,
        paging: false,
        sort: false
    });

    const chartData1 = getChartData(table1);
    const chartData2 = getChartData(table2);

    initializeChart('demo-output', 'FY 2023', chartData1, 'pie');
    initializeChart('demo-output2', 'FY 2022', chartData2, 'bar');

    var categories = [];
    var allSeriesData = [];

    var table = $("#example2").DataTable({
        searching: false,
        responsive: true,
        lengthChange: false,
        ordering: false,
        info: false,
        paging: false,
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
            let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);

            var headers = api.columns().header().toArray();
            headers.forEach(function (heading, index) {
                if (index > 0 && index < headers.length) {
                    categories.push($(heading).html());
                }
            });

            let rows = api.rows().data().toArray();
            rows.forEach(function (row) {
                group = {
                    name: '',
                    data: []
                };
                row.forEach(function (cell, idx) {
                    if (idx == 0) {
                        group.name = cell;
                    } else if (idx < row.length) {
                        group.data.push(parseFloat(cell.replace(/,/g, '')));
                    }
                });
                allSeriesData.push(group);
            });
        }
    });

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        }
    });

    var myChart = Highcharts.chart("chart-A", {
        chart: {
            type: "column",
            borderColor: 'lightgray',
            borderWidth: 1,
            marginTop: 50
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '{point.key}<br/>',
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        legend: {
            symbolRadius: 0,
            itemStyle: {
                color: '#000000',
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        },
        colors: ['#003489', '#ED7D31', '#A5A5A5', '#FFC000', '#5B9BD5'],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: "Trends"
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: '600',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: false,
            tickInterval: 10,
            max: 60,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);
                },
                style: {
                    fontWeight: '600',
                    fontSize: '16px',
                    color: '#000000'
                }
            }
        },
        series: allSeriesData
    });

    $('.usa-button').on('click', function () {
        var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

        if (buttonId === 'previous') {
            $('#chart2').show();
            $('#chart1').hide();
            $('#chart3').hide();
        } else if (buttonId === 'trend') {
            $('#chart2').hide();
            $('#chart1').hide();
            $('#chart3').show();
        } else {
            $('#chart2').hide();
            $('#chart1').show();
            $('#chart3').hide();
        }

        $('.usa-button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $('#current').addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/dataTables.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/dataTables.js"></script>

 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>




<div class="ar-controls grid-row tablet:flex-justify-start">
<div class="tablet:grid-col-auto margin-bottom-205"><button id="current" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">one</button> <button id="previous" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">two</button> <button id="trend" class="usa-button usa-button--outline" title="Select to see related information below">three</button></div>
</div>

<div id="chart1">
<div id="demo-output" class="chart-display" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 500px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example1" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">2023</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row">ABC</td>
<td>45.9%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">DEF</td>
<td>22.0%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row">GHI</td>
<td>13.6%</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div id="chart2" style=" display: none;">
<div id="demo-output2" class="chart-display2" style=" margin-bottom: 2em; height: 680px; border: solid 1px lightgray;"></div>

<table id="example" class="display" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col">2022</th>
<th scope="col">Percent</th>
</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td>LLL</td>
<td>51.90%</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>MMM</td>
<td>18.60%</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

<div id="chart3" style=" display: none;">
<div id="chart-A" style=" width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

<table class="row-border stripe no-footer cell-border padding-top-5" id="example2" style=" width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr>
<th>Year</th>
<th>column1</th>
<th>column2</th>
<th>column3</th>

</tr>

</thead>
<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: left; white-space: nowrap;">FY19</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">42.7%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">17.3%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">9.5%</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td scope="row" style=" text-align: left;">FY20</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">49.5%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">16.3%</td>
<td style=" text-align: left;">3.4%</td>

</tr>


</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, legend contains items for each series of the chart. In your bar chart, you have a single series with two data points. In order to show each column inside the legend, you can split the data into separate series:

```
series: [{
  data: [{x: 0, y: 65.5 }],
  name: 'Bar A' 
}, {
  data: [{ x: 1, y: 54.3 }],
  name: 'Bar B' 
}]
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wd58exon/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend

You can also create a custom legend, where each point will be assigned as an item inside the legend container.

**Docs:** https://highcharts.freshdesk.com/a/solutions/articles/44002324228

Comment: I am not sure if this answers my question. Is there a way you can update my example as I dont want to define the values in highcharts javascript. Instead it should pull values from the datatable below (similar to pie chart)

Comment: Charts for Button one (pie chart) and Button three (column chart) are fine. They show the X axis and Y axis values from the corresponding tables below. However, the problem I am facing is with Button two - Bar chart. Similar to other charts, for the bar chart too, I am trying to display the axis values from the datatable below. Column 2022 values should be X axis and Percent column as Y axis. The legend should also display X axis (column 2022) data.

Comment: In my original answer, the example code shows how you can aggregate your data from tables into separate series. In your demo, you're creating a singular series with multiple data points, which works well for pie charts, as each data point in pie chart reflects one item in legend.
In order to achieve described result in your example, you'd have to modify the method responsible for pulling data from tables and update chart config, since in 2nd chart, you want two separate series instead of one with two points.
**Demo:** [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lqktzymo/)